# Jquery Globalize package

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, date, unobtrusive-validation, jquery-globalization

I'm very new to Visual Studio 2015 so I apologize if this is a dumb question. I downloaded this jquery globalize package will aids me with validation of dates from different locale.

I have no idea what the scripts are for or how they are use. Are they like classes where we can use help methods?

I have created method which is used to create new users in my MVC4 with Entity Framework database.

Right now it's based in US which is MM/DD/YYYY but I want it to be DD/MM/YYYY

Views\User\Create.cshtml (Snippet of code)

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrollmentDate)
    </div>

    <p> <input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
```

This is what my script folder looks like after I installed my globalization package.

[Script folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebOBY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the exact same problem but I think you can just comment out the jquery statements but remember it's only for TESTING purpose and not for development because you'll disable the client-side authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However I want a permenantly solution for this problem as it's only covering up the issue but not fixing it

Answer (score 1):

[ASP .NET MVC DateTime globalization. "The field Date must be a date."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287971/asp-net-mvc-datetime-globalization-the-field-date-must-be-a-date)

Had the exact same problem so take a look at the answer and hopefully it helps!